# jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jq, ssh-agent

I am trying to run some jq command over ssh-agent in a Jenkins pipeline. But I am getting the following error:
Trying to run:
`

```
        stage("common-infra-deployment"){
            steps{
                sshagent (credentials: ['test-private-key']){
                    script{
                       
                        sh '''
                        sudo ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hci@10.x.x.x "
                        jq '.outputs | {"kubeconfig-file"}' terraform.tfstate;
                        "
                        '''

                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

`

Error:
`

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

`

terraform.tfstate
`

```
{
"outputs": {
    "kubeconfig-file": {
      "value": "/home/chi/jenkins-terraform/config",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "master-node-ip": {
      "value": "x.x.x.x",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "master-node-vm-name": {
      "value": "v1",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "worker-node-ip": {
      "value": "x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "worker-node-vm-names": {
      "value": "v2, v3, v4",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

`

I tried \ to escape '-' and '{}' but nothings working out.
I want the jq to be executed over ssh session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape your double quotes inside your double quotes:

```
sudo ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hci@10.x.x.x "
jq '.outputs | {\"kubeconfig-file\"}' terraform.tfstate;
"
```

Perhaps the backslash needs to be escaped itself:

```
sudo ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hci@10.x.x.x "
jq '.outputs | {\\"kubeconfig-file\\"}' terraform.tfstate;
"
```

Comment: No luck! Same result!

Comment: @KapilYadav can you somehow enable debug output of which exact command is run? Could you try double backslashes, i.e. `{\\"kubeconfig-file\\"}`?

Comment: Double backslashes seems to be working. Thanks! - @knittl